# Is there a standard C# lib, like Apache commons for java?

Tags: c#

Php has PEAR, PERL has CPAN and Java has Appache commons.
Short and simple : is there one accepted library for c# extensions/cookbook recipes?

(Feel free to close if exact duplicate, i suspect it somewhat, but don't seem to find it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is a C# Commons similar to Java Commons.

It's relatively new but pretty good. It's [CommonLibrary.NET](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.com.
commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/

My company uses a mix of Java and C#. I'm now using both Java Commons and C# CommonLibrary.NET and so far it's pretty good. It's got most( not all ) of the same components that Java Commons has plus some other ones.

Comment: codeplex no longer exists... found this https://github.com/uwx/CommonLibrary.NET but there is no nuget package .... it just seems dead :(

Answer (score 5):

No; the codebase is a bit more fragmented.

Obviously there is the core framework classes (in all the different version levels), but other than that there is little concensus... codeplex has a number of useful libraries, as does code.google.com etc - but you'll generally be picking specific tools from specific community projects.

Comment: coming from you, I'm afraid it is right, and i might as well accept the answer right away...

not the answer i was hoping for though